# MySQL substring index delimiter issue

Tags: mysql

New to all this but I have a table called Table1 with a column name `cat1` contents is `:` delimited:

```
info:something:else
```

I want to select the information to the right of the second `:`

I am using the following statement:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(cat1, ':', -1) FROM Table1
```

It gives me an error

> ending quote expected ' near (near)

but if I change the `:` to something like `;` it will run with no error.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Don't store delimited data, just use multiple rows. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad There also is no `near` in your query, where does that come from?

Comment: [First normal form - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)

Comment: Works for me. Can you share the PHP code you use to call this query?

Comment: Hi I am using phpmyadmin to write the code not using PHP directly. The error was in the form of a red cross to the left of my script and said exactly that. I ran the script and it would just hang there for a very long time. I have just ran it again and it has worked though it took like 15 mins but the mysql says it only took 0.051 seconds. This is really strange.

Comment: The PHPmyadmin interface lies about execution time frequently, use the real mysql interface to get the real execution time.